# Game Crashes During Play

Tags: crashes

After playing [Family Guy](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tinyco.familyguy&hl=en) for several years, it suddenly began to crash while playing. The app is saved to my SD card and there appears to be plenty of space left on the card as well as on the device.

What might be causing the crashes and how can I stop them?

Answer (score 0):

**Why?**

SD cards are usually slower than internal storage. Never put games in the SD card.

Another reason could be that there were big updates to the game and slowly could have made the game crash at times.

**The Fix?**

Take the game out of the SD card. Only use SD cards for photos & videos, light apps, and music.

Answer (score 0):

according to your description, I think the main reason is that the game is **placed in the SD card**, causing the card to slow down or even crash. The local storage and SD card reading speed are inconsistent, and using a high-speed and high-quality SD card will reduce this problem.

Besides, there may be several reasons:

1. Your Android phone has **too much cache**, and when the phone is too cached, the app will run slower and crash.
2. There are **too many running programs in the background** of your Android phone. The closed app just exits the desktop and is still running in the background.
3. The game is **not compatible with the system**. Too high or too low.
4. **Missing data package**. Crash is also caused by the lack of data packets when running the game. This can happen if the packet .obb file is deleted by mistake. 
   Like most game of Gamaloft, if you lost .obb file, it will crash.

If you don't plan to change a mobile phone, you need to **clean your phone** often:

1. Navigate to Settings on your phone. Setting>>Apps>>Choose the app you don’t like>> uninstall or force stop.
2. Navigate to Settings on your phone. Setting>>Storage>>Cached Data.
3. Use **Agile File Manager** to free up your storage. It can simply delete cached files, along with miscellaneous files that are larger than 10 MB. The Boost option can closes apps you’re not using that are still running in the background.
4. The last thing to say is that for Android phones, restarting the phone can solve more than half of the problems. When your device has been running for a long time, and if it is a low-end phone. Rebooting the phone will erase all blocked apps and fix freezes and crashes on apps on Android devices.